# Rasterizing shared edge of two adjacent polygons

Tags: opengl, directx, metal, vulkan, rasterizing

In scanline rendering, when rasterizing polygons (usually triangles), if two polygons share an edge (ie. they share two consecutive vertices), the pixels at this shared edge ought to be rendered only once. (This is necessary for several reasons. The most common and obvious one is when using a translucent texture: If the shared edge pixels were to be rendered twice, it would affect the transparency of those pixels, making the shared edge less transparent and thus visible.)

All scanline renderers, including graphics hardware, need to handle this problem. However, for the life of me I can't find a clear, easy-to-understand, efficient algorithm for this, even after extensive googling.

I'm not looking only for theory and vague descriptions of solutions, but actual concrete pseudocode. Preferably algorithms that are being actually used in renderers and graphics hardware. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Google "rasterization rules". Specifically "top left rasterization rule" (the most common one)

Comment: Also check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703412/how-does-opengl-render-its-triangles)

Comment: I have googled that, and many other similar keywords, and found nothing useful. Most results simply describe what OpenGL/Direct3D do, but they do not give any kind of algorithm. A few pages give an actual rendering algorithm, but so far I have only found extremely unoptimized inefficient algorithms that basically just go over the entire screen and see (using a large amount of multiplications on each pixel) whether it's inside the triangle or not. (For example, one such page comments: "This version is valid as a proof of concept but highly unoptimized", which is rather telling.)

Comment: The top left rule always seemed ill-defined to me. The Vulkan spec does not even specify what the rule is, just that one of the samples wins.

Comment: I changed the tags to try to make the question more likely to be seen by the relevant experts.